# Can't seem to get my code on line 6 to run

Tags: jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var divMouseDown;
    $('.iphonepowerbutton').mousedown(function() {
        $('.iphonepowerbutton').width('1px');
        divMouseDown = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.iphonescreen').css('background-color', 'white', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.iphonetime').show();
                    $('.iphonedate').show();
                    $('.iphoneapplelogo').hide;
                    $('.iphonescreen').css('background-color', 'black');
                }, 3500);
            });
            $('.iphoneapplelogo').show();
            $('.iphonepowerbutton').hide();
            $('.iphonepowerbutton2').show();
        }, 2000);
    });
    $('.iphonepowerbutton').mouseup(function() {
        $('.iphonepowerbutton').width('2px');
        if (divMouseDown) {
            clearTimeout(divMouseDown);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get line 6 to function when the function on line 5 runs.
Is the code correct, Is it my browser, or am i missing something?
I'm trying to start start a function when a function is ran.

Comment: I don't think you can use third argument with jQuery.css()

Comment: What are you wanting to happen?  Please get this down to a [mcve].

Comment: If you want a gradual CSS transition you should be using `.animate()`, not `.css()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have callbacks on the `.css` method in jQuery because the CSS changes are instantanious so there's really no point.

Just put the rest of the code after it.

In case you're waiting for a CSS transition to complete, you'd have to calculate that in manually.

Comment: @ShroudKing If this is the correct answer, you can use the green checkmark to set it as such. And welcome to SO!